# On Yanqi Xu's 2016 joint undergraduate math research project with Dr. Judy Holdener at Kenyon College

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

In what follows, we let $\sigma(X)$ denote the sum of the divisors of the positive integer $X$.  Denote the abundancy index of $X$ by $I(X)=\sigma(X)/X$, and the deficiency of $X$ by $D(X)=2X-\sigma(X)$.  Finally, let $s(X)=\sigma(X)-X$ denote the sum of the aliquot divisors of $X$.

This is a question about Yanqi Xu's 2016 joint undergraduate math research project with Dr. Judy Holdener at Kenyon College, titled *Characterization of the Positive Integers with Abundancy Index of the Form $(2x-1)/x$*.  (A copy of the poster presentation is available via the following [hyperlink](http://biology.kenyon.edu/HHMI/posters_2016/xuy.pdf).)

In the abstract of the paper, it is stated in the fourth sentence that

> Rational numbers of the form $(2x-1)/x$ are important since both even and odd perfect numbers have a divisor with abundancy index of this form.

Let $M = 2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$ be an even perfect number, and let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number.

Clearly,
$$I(2^{p-1}) = \frac{2^p - 1}{2^{p-1}} = \frac{2x_1 - 1}{x_1}$$
where $x_1 = 2^{p-1}$.  (In other words, $2^{p-1}$ is an even almost perfect number, since it is a power of two.)

However,
$$I(p^k) = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p^{k+1} - p^k}$$
and
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(p^k)} = \frac{2(p^{k+1} - p^k)}{p^{k+1} - 1}$$
so clearly $p^k$ is not almost perfect (since $p$ must be odd).

Additionally, since
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)} \geq 3$$
(see the paper [[Dris, 2012]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html)), then clearly $n^2$ is likewise not almost perfect.  (Similarly, it can be proved that $n$ and $q^k n$ are not almost perfect.)

So I think the trivial divisor $1$ of an odd perfect number has the required abundancy index
$$I(1) = 1 = \frac{2\cdot{1} - 1}{1} = \frac{2x_2 - 1}{x_2}$$
where $x_2 = 1$.

Here is my question:

> Is there any other divisor $m > 1$ of an odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ such that
>   $$I(m) = \frac{2x - 1}{x}$$
>   for some positive integer $x$?

Comment: This looks like it probably should be on StackOverFlow

Comment: @IAmNoOne, did you mean MathOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following answer is based on a theorem in a paper (to appear) communicated to Dris by Holdener (co-authored with Rachfal).**

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$.  Suppose that $k>1$.

Consider the proper factor
$$q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2.$$

This has abundancy index
$$I\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2\bigg) = I\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)I(n^2) = I\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)\cdot\frac{2}{I(q^k)} = \frac{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 1}{q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}(q - 1)}\cdot\frac{2q^k (q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1}.$$

Since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, $k+1$ is even, so that
$$q^{k+1} - 1 = \bigg(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 1\bigg)\cdot\bigg(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1\bigg).$$

Canceling the common factor
$$q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} (q - 1)\bigg(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 1\bigg)$$
in the numerator and denominator of
$$I\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2\bigg),$$
we get
$$I\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2\bigg) = \frac{2q^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1} = 2 - \frac{1}{\bigg(\frac{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}}+1}{2}\bigg)},$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$.

Suppose that the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture that $k=1$ holds.

Then
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q)} = \frac{2q}{q+1} = 2 - \frac{1}{(q+1)/2} = \frac{2((q+1)/2) - 1}{(q+1)/2},$$
where $(q+1)/2$ is an integer (since $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$).

It remains to consider the case when $k>1$.  (Note that $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.)